# iPhone camera app for low-res photos

Tags: ios, photography, iphone-app, camera

I'm looking for an iPhone app that can take photos at small file sizes. Sometimes I just want to snap a photo of some text or a memo, and I don't need such photos represented in high detail taking up storage space on my iPhone (or computer hard drive once copied). Does such an app exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at [Simple Resize](https://itunes.apple.com/app/simple-resize/id327776379?mt=8)?

How to use:

1. Choose photo from your library / Take a picture.
2. Set saved photo size.
3. Save.